# Why doesn't eclipse correctly format #define?

Tags: c++, formatting, eclipse-cdt

Giving the following code :

```
void func(int var1, int var2, int var3, int var4, int var5, int var6, int var7, int var8, int var9);            
#define A_DEFINE_VARIABLE 1
int a_dynamic_variable = 1;
func(a_dynamic_variable,a_dynamic_variable,A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,a_dynamic_variable,A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,a_dynamic_variable,A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,A_DEFINE_VARIABLE);
```

After a first formatting call of Eclipse (ctrl+shift+F), I get the wanted formatted (I've edited the K&R style) :

```
void func(int var1,
          int var2,
          int var3,
          int var4,
          int var5,
          int var6,
          int var7,
          int var8,
          int var9);
#define A_DEFINE_VARIABLE 1
int a_dynamic_variable = 1;
func(a_dynamic_variable,
     a_dynamic_variable,
     A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,
     a_dynamic_variable,
     A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,
     A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,
     a_dynamic_variable,
     A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,
     A_DEFINE_VARIABLE);
```

But after a second call, I get :

```
void func(int var1,
          int var2,
          int var3,
          int var4,
          int var5,
          int var6,
          int var7,
          int var8,
          int var9);
#define A_DEFINE_VARIABLE 1
int a_dynamic_variable = 1;
func(a_dynamic_variable, a_dynamic_variable,
A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,
     a_dynamic_variable,
     A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,
     A_DEFINE_VARIABLE, a_dynamic_variable,
     A_DEFINE_VARIABLE,
     A_DEFINE_VARIABLE);
```

Formatting is now broken...
Is this a bug? Or is there something wrong in my configuration?

Comment: It would help if you said how you modified K&R, because the standard K&R built-in one works fine. If I play around with random settings in the formatter I can cause similar (but not identical) behaviour. Therefore, please be explicit (include version numbers of tools!) but I suspect you have found a bug in an untested combination of all the possible formatting options. Please [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT)

Comment: I'm currently using this version of Eclipse : Version: Neon Milestone 4 (4.6.0M4) Build id: 20151218-1739. But the issue occurs with any other version of Eclipse. It's a bit complicated to  post here my K&R style, so I'm going to report it as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug (http://eclip.se/487235)! And also thank you very much for taking the time to test milestone/pre-release Eclipse builds!